# Microsoft WordDOCX Nested list solution is not working as expected

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello i try to fix the nested list elements in XSLT 2.0,transformation to HTML and my XML is like above;

```
<w:p w:rsidR="008845A9" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="008845A9" w:rsidP="004E414C">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
    </w:pPr>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="001207E2" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="001207E2" w:rsidP="004E414C">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
            <w:numId w:val="5"/>
        </w:numPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t>First Item</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="00AD36E6" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00AD36E6" w:rsidP="004E414C">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
            <w:numId w:val="5"/>
        </w:numPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t>Second Item</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="00AD36E6" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00AD36E6" w:rsidP="004E414C">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
            <w:numId w:val="5"/>
        </w:numPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t>Third Item</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="002B7A91" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="002B7A91" w:rsidP="004E414C">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="2"/>
            <w:numId w:val="5"/>
        </w:numPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t>Third Item – One</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="002B7A91" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="002B7A91" w:rsidP="004E414C">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="2"/>
            <w:numId w:val="5"/>
        </w:numPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Third Item </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="006551A3" w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t>–</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> Two</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="006551A3" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="006551A3" w:rsidP="004E414C">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="3"/>
            <w:numId w:val="6"/>
        </w:numPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Sample Item </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00554D9D" w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t>A</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="006551A3" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="00554D9D" w:rsidP="004E414C">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="3"/>
            <w:numId w:val="6"/>
        </w:numPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t>Sample Item B</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="002B7A91" w:rsidRPr="001509B0" w:rsidRDefault="002B7A91" w:rsidP="004E414C">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="AppBody-Description"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
            <w:numId w:val="5"/>
        </w:numPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t>Fo</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00565721" w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t>u</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="001509B0">
        <w:t>rth Item</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

And the full XSLT

```
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <ol>
                <xsl:call-template name="grouping">
                    <xsl:with-param name="par" select="w:document/w:body/w:p[1]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </ol>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="grouping">
    <xsl:param name="par"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$par/w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl/@w:val >0">
            <xsl:variable name="level" select="$par/w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl/@w:val"/>
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="$par/w:r/w:t"/>
            </li>
            <xsl:call-template name="order">
                <xsl:with-param name="par" select="$par/following-sibling::w:p[1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="levelPrevious" select="$level"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="grouping">
                <xsl:with-param name="par" select="$par/following-sibling::w:p[2]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:if test="$par/following-sibling::w:p[1]">
                <xsl:call-template name="grouping">
                    <xsl:with-param name="par" select="$par/following-sibling::w:p[1]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="order">
    <xsl:param name="par"/>
    <xsl:param name="levelPrevious"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$par/w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl/@w:val > $levelPrevious">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$par/w:r/w:t"/>
                </li>
                <xsl:call-template name="grouping">
                    <xsl:with-param name="par" select="$par/following-sibling::w:p[1]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </ol>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$par/w:r/w:t"/>
                </li>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

And the Result is :

```
1.First Item
2.Second Item
3.Third Item
   1.Third Item – One
   2.Third Item – Two
       1.Sample Item A
       2.Sample Item B
       3.Fo u rth Item
   3.Sample Item B
   4.Fo u rth Item
4.Third Item – Two
   1.Sample Item A
   2.Sample Item B
   3.Fo u rth Item
5.Sample Item B
6.Fo u rth Item
```

Expected Result is :

```
1.First Item
2.Second Item
3.Third Item
       a.Third Item – One
       b.Third Item – Two
          I.Sample Item A
          II.Sample Item B
4.Fourth Item
```

The thing is that i dont know how to add the 4.item into first group and the third item also iterating itself in other level.How can i fix this problem any idea?

*Edit:I am almost there just need to get rid of this copied elements after the fourth item!

Comment: Please show source XML and **full** XSLT for reproducibility on our end.

Comment: It is almost impossible to put it here the entire code..What i am trying to understand is how the recursive functions work.In this case i am doing something very stupid and cant see what it is.I dont know if i can upload the files some other websites and share here.

Comment: Usually XSLT scripts are not that long and we only need a sample source XML. You can try pastebin or GitHub gists to dump code/data.

Comment: Okay i edited the XSLT and added the sample XML file from DOCX.

Comment: I attempted a solution but what really is tough is determining the nested list items as their original structure are all same-level `<w:p>` tags. Here, in this pseudo data file, it says *First Item*, *Second Item*, ... but no where is there an indicator for *Third Item - One* or *Sample Item* to be nested. How to determine nested items?

Comment: They are going through the be nested by the w:val Ex:w:val=1 w:val=2 these  are  determining the nested levels in the list.each level of w:val is  another nest.I was trying to group them by w:val and in each group should be listed inside if the w:val remains the same.

Comment: days after still have no solution for that..

Comment: That info was exactly what I needed! I will get back to you shortly with possibly a simpler solution. Busy today. One question: will there be up to three nests?

Comment: For the question:No,only for this document i have 3 nests but it could be also more than that.Thats why i tried to restrict it with 2 values.If you look at the XSLT code i start with the tag if w:val >0 and the "levelPrevious" so it is checking everytime if the nests keep going or not.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this XSLT 1.0 solution using a recursive template. Do note your XML input was not fully complete as the very important top tags and namespace URI were not included. Below XSLT assumes the following XML structure. If actual XML is still different, of course change the correspoinding XSLT references accordingly.

**XML**

```
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:body>
    <!-- repeat <w:p> tags -->
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="w">
 <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" indent="yes"/> 
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/w:document/w:body">
      <html>
          <head>
              <title/>
          </head>
          <body>
            <ol>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="w:p[w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl/@w:val='1']"/>
            </ol>
          </body>
     </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w:p">
      <li><xsl:apply-templates select="w:r"/></li>                
      <xsl:call-template name="nest">
         <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'a'"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="par" select="2"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="val" select="following-sibling::*"/>             
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="nest">
      <xsl:param name="type"/>
      <xsl:param name="par"/>
      <xsl:param name="val"/>

      <xsl:if test="$val[1]/w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl/@w:val=$par">
         <ol type="{$type}">
            <xsl:for-each select="$val">
               <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl/@w:val=$par">
                  <li><xsl:apply-templates select="w:r"/></li>                  
                  <xsl:call-template name="nest">
                     <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'I'"/>
                     <xsl:with-param name="par" select="$par+1"/>
                     <xsl:with-param name="val" select="following-sibling::*"/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
               </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </ol>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML** Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>
      <li>First Item</li>
      <li>Second Item</li>
      <li>Third Item</li>
      <ol type="a">
        <li>Third Item - One</li>
        <li>Third Item - Two</li>
        <ol type="I">
          <li>Sample Item A</li>
          <li>Sample Item A</li>
        </ol>
      </ol>
      <li>Fourth Item</li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: HTML Output]

Comment: It is working thank you but when i add it to my code it is not.I will try to fix the problem today but the code itself is working.Thank you very much.Highly appreciated :)

Comment: Great! Again, your actual XML may differ from my tested version (i.e., root/namespace). Let me know if you run into issues.